# How to show an dialog when "out of memory" is occured in android?

Tags: android

I have developed an application. In some devices my application is running "Out of memory" then app is crashing and saying "unfortunately  has stopped working".

I want to show a dialog whenever my application runs out of memory instead of crashing the application.

Let me be clear :

When my application runs out of memory i want to show Dialog from application saying "Oops ! Unexpected error occured. Please try again later ". App should not be crashed.

Comment: OS shows that itself, you don't need to do that

Comment: you need to avoid out of memory. you need not show dialog for out of memory..

Comment: please read my question well @Apurva

Comment: You can make the block inside try, catch also increase the large heap in manifest  android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: You should never catch error. You need to resolve errors and give good user experience. Errors are not like exception where you can catch and show dialog. Bad practice to catch error

Comment: then why your app throw out of memory in the first place? does it will be better if you fix that before you use try catch the exception?

Comment: Guys !! I know "Out of memory" is a bad thing. I tried and fixed it in many devices. In some low end devices "Out of memory" occuring. For those I want to show dialog. i

Answer (score 0):

The "OutOfMemory crash" you're talking about, is caused by an exception. There are multiple things you can do, should do and shouldn't do.

Ideally, you should never catch outOfMemory under normal circumstances. Instead, you should try to avoid this by memory management in your app. See [Managing your app's memory](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html) for more information.

Besides, If you really want to know how to do it, you can identify your potential memory leaks and catch them with a `try-catch` block and do whatever you want to with them (never advised to do so).

The best solution is to identify your leaks with [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](https://eclipse.org/mat/) and try to avoid them within your app.